# How to render 2-React-Components next to each other in the same row using TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have a **NextJS** application using Nextra and **TailwindCSS**.

What I want to achieve is a Row that contains 2 components next to each other:

```
----------
COMP  COMP
----------
```

But when I use the following code, I get this:

```
----------
COMP
COMP
----------
```

My mdx-File contains the following:

```
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap justify-between w-full">
            <External />
            <External />
        </div>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Consider removing `flex-wrap` or otherwise checking the mdx file is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: flex-col will put it after each other vertically. By removing flex-col it is supposed to put elements horizontally but you can also try flex-row instead.